# Inclusion Table of Contents in Table of Contents itself using tocbibind

Tags: table-of-contents, tocbibind

[image: warning after using tocbibind but not using nottoc]

I want to add bibliography to my list of figures, so i'm using tocbibind. But, I want to include ToC, list of tables, and list of figures, to my ToC. So, I delete the nottoc, and these warnings came out.

What should I do to fix these warnings?

Comment: Please provide an MWE (from `\documentclass...` to `\end{document}`) that we can compile that shows your problem. I tried `\usepackage[chapter]{tocbibind}` with a simple `report` class document and no warnings given. I've no idea how to get the `skripsidtntf` (sp?) class. What program did you use to compile your document? The `tocbibind` package code has no notion of `tocbasic`.

Comment: Given that you load `tocbibind` on line 115, probably somewhere before that you load the `tocbasic` package, or you load some other package that in turn loads `tocbasic` internally. As the warning says, `tocbibind` should be loaded _before_ `tocbasic`, so just moving `\RequirePackage[chapter]{tocbibind}` to an earlier position in the file would probably resolve the issue.